# Yii2 - save() doesn't save

Tags: php, yii2

I have Order model, and I want to change "status" in one of orders. I execute such a code:

```
 $order = new Order();
        $new = $order->find()->where(['status' => 'new'])->orderBy(['id' => SORT_ASC])->one();
        if($new){
           $new->status = "queued";
           $ok = $new->save();
           return true;
        }
```

And, `$new` is the record that I want, so that's ok. So, when I try to save changes, it doen't do it, and `$ok` gives me "false". I have no idea why, I have used `save()` before and never have problems with it.

**Update:**
Found mistake, it was not connected to `save()` function.

Comment: You can see if there are any validation errors by displaying result of `$new->getErrors()` after `save()` has been called.

Comment: Okay, I found one mistake in rules that I had - `getErrors()` helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Your value is not saving because of model validation, You can skip model validation by putting false.

```
$order = new Order();
    $new = $order->find()->where(['status' => 'new'])->orderBy(['id' => SORT_ASC])->one();
    if($new){
       $new->status = "queued";
       $ok = $new->save(false); // skip model validation
       return true;
    }
```